# Is this correct way of checking SHA256 on Mac?

Tags: java, compression, checksum

I've downloaded the tar file for OpenJDK 12 for macOS from [here](https://jdk.java.net/12/).

The SHA256 for the same provided [here](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk12.0.1/69cfe15208a647278a19ef0990eea691/12/GPL/openjdk-12.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar.gz.sha256) suggests it should be:

```
cba6f42f82496f62c51fb544e243d440984d442bdc906550a30428d8be6189e5
```

However when I run the checksum on my laptop it comes out different.

```
$ gsha256sum openjdk-12.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar
dba2de6203b798f1931c1158e0eb89227ef855a6f4515d8d5a7d2e3a9f8c18bb  openjdk-12.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar
$ openssl dgst -sha256 openjdk-12.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar
SHA256(openjdk-12.0.1_osx-x64_bin.tar)= dba2de6203b798f1931c1158e0eb89227ef855a6f4515d8d5a7d2e3a9f8c18b
```

Am I incorrectly checking the checksum?

If so, what is the right way of doing so, and is this tar file safe to install on my laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your post it looks like you're comparing the ungzipped `.tar` file, which your browser/os might have 'helpfully' unpacked for you after the download. You need to compute the checksum on the `.tar.gz` file.

When I run the command on the `.tar.gz` file, the checksum comes out as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Sorry for not noticing something so obvious.

Comment: The automatic decompression seems to come from Safari; instructions to disable it are [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/961/how-to-stop-safari-from-unzipping-files-after-download).